# Removing directory for oracle installation

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

After Oracle 12c DB is installed, can the directory unzipped from `linuxx64_12201_database.zip` remove without problems?

Comment: So long as *none* of the target directory locations (Oracle Base, Home, Data directory etc)  specified during the installation process  reference that directory then yes it is safe to delete. If in doubt, just rename it to `XX{name}XX`, leave it for a week or two, and if no issues then delete.

Comment: Yes you can remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can because this directory is only used as installation source (assuming that you don't create ORACLE_HOME in this source directory of course).